# Making ui Image to perfect circle in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a UIImage View in table view cell to a perfect circle by code in Swift.
At first, I put `img.layer.cornerRadius = 35` in my code and it makes my image almost like a circle. Then instead of passing a number to the corner radius, I was trying to write that part by code, something like `img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.height / 2`. However, this code makes the UIImage square (doesn't apply corner radius). I am not sure why this happens. Could anyone please explain why this happens and how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

```
class RepositoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    let userImageView: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.height / 2
        // img.layer.cornerRadius = 35 <= this code works
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.backgroundColor = .black
    
        return img
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
        addSubview(userImageView)
        containerView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(repositoryNameLabel)
        addSubview(containerView)
        addSubview(starNumLabel)

        configureViewComponents()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func configureViewComponents() {
    
    setUserImageConstraints()
    
}


func setUserImageConstraints() {
    userImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    userImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    userImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    userImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    userImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: cornerRadius is set when your image view has not been rendered (you use lazy declaration), at that time its frame is still zero.
So let's give the image view a frame in the init, or set cornerRadius in awakeFromNib()/layoutSubviews().

Comment: Anyway, corner radius is a poor way to make a circular image. Instead, mask to a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `let img = UIImageView()` -> `frame == zero`

You can do like this:

```
class RepositoryCell: UITableViewCell {
...

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.height / 2
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use RxSwift, you can simply call `img.cornerHalf()`,

it uses Key Path Observe

```
let userImageView: UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    // ...
    img.cornerHalf()
    // ...
    return img
}()
```

with the assist code below

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa


extension UIView{
    
    func cornerHalf(){
        clipsToBounds = true
        rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.bounds))
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                // _ : CGRect? in
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height * 0.5
            }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
    
    
}
```